# OpenMP omp fork 2 threads much faster than fork 4 threads, why?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, openmp

I am learning parallel computing. I wrote the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
void Usage(char* prog_name);
double f(double x);    /* Function we're integrating */
double Local_trap(double a, double b, int n);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double  global_result = 0.0;  /* Store result in global_result */
    double  a, b;                 /* Left and right endpoints      */
    int     n;                    /* Total number of trapezoids    */
    int     thread_count, repeat_times;
    double *time_fork, *time_elapsed, *time_join, *time_end;
    double global_start, global_finish, global_time = 0.0;

    printf("Enter a, b, n, thread_count and repeat times, n mod thread_count should = 0.\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %d %d %d", &a, &b, &n, &thread_count, &repeat_times);

    if (n % thread_count != 0)
        Usage(argv[0]);

    time_fork    = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(double));
    time_elapsed = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(double));
    time_join    = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(double));
    time_end     = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(double));

    if ((NULL == time_elapsed) || (NULL == time_fork) || (NULL == time_join) || (NULL == time_end))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_count)
    for (int i = 0;i < thread_count;i++)
    {
        time_fork[i] = 0.0;
        time_elapsed[i] = 0.0;
        time_join[i] = 0.0;
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < repeat_times;i++)
    {
        global_start = omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count) reduction(+:global_result)
        {
            /* new code to calculate time elapsed */
            #pragma omp barrier
            double my_start, my_finish, my_elapsed;
            int my_rank = omp_get_thread_num();
            my_start = omp_get_wtime();
            time_fork[my_rank] += (my_start - global_start);

            /* original code to calculate trap */
            global_result += Local_trap(a, b, n);

            /* new code to calculate time elapsed */
            my_finish  = omp_get_wtime();
            my_elapsed = my_finish - my_start;
            time_elapsed[my_rank] += my_elapsed;
            time_end[my_rank] = my_finish;
        }
        global_finish = omp_get_wtime();

        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_count)
        for (int j = 0;j < thread_count;j++)
        {
            time_join[j] += (global_finish - time_end[j]);
        }

        global_time += (global_finish - global_start);
    }

    printf("The global run time is %.14f seconds.\n", global_time/repeat_times);
    for(int i = 0; i < thread_count;i++)
    {
        printf("The thread %d runs  %.14f seconds.\n", i, time_elapsed[i]/repeat_times);
        printf("The thread %d forks %.14f seconds.\n", i, time_fork[i]/repeat_times);
        printf("The thread %d joins %.14f seconds.\n", i, time_join[i]/repeat_times);
    }

    printf("With n = %d trapezoids, our estimate\n", n);
    printf("of the integral from %f to %f = %.14e\n", a, b, global_result);

    free(time_fork);
    free(time_elapsed);
    free(time_join);
    free(time_end);
    return 0;
}  /* main */
void Usage(char* prog_name)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <number of threads>\n", prog_name);
    fprintf(stderr, "   number of trapezoids must be evenly divisible by\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "   number of threads\n");
    exit(0);
}
double f(double x)
{
    double return_val;
    return_val = x*x;
    return return_val;
}  /* f */

double Local_trap(double a, double b, int n)
{
    double  h, x, my_result;
    double  local_a, local_b;
    int  i, local_n;
    int my_rank = omp_get_thread_num();
    int thread_count = omp_get_num_threads();

    h = (b-a)/n;
    local_n = n/thread_count;
    local_a = a + my_rank*local_n*h;
    local_b = local_a + local_n*h;
    my_result = (f(local_a) + f(local_b))/2.0;
    for (i = 1; i <= local_n-1; i++)
    {
        x = local_a + i*h;
        my_result += f(x);
    }
    my_result = my_result*h;

    return my_result;
}
```

I compiled on ubuntu 14.04, my laptop is i3, 4 threads, command is `gcc -g3 -Wall -fopenmp -std=c99 -o Assignment2 Assignment2.c`

the output for 1 2 12000 2 10

```
The global run time is 0.00013472399987 seconds.
The thread 0 runs  0.00013350439967 seconds.
The thread 0 forks 0.00000079790025 seconds.
The thread 0 joins 0.00000042169995 seconds.
The thread 1 runs  0.00013322920022 seconds.
The thread 1 forks 0.00000062119998 seconds.
The thread 1 joins 0.00000087359967 seconds.
With n = 12000 trapezoids, our estimate
of the integral from 1.000000 to 2.000000 = 2.33333333449074e+01
```

the output for 1 2 12000 4 10

```
The global run time is 0.00781751800023 seconds.
The thread 0 runs  0.00006403259995 seconds.
The thread 0 forks 0.00621278830040 seconds.
The thread 0 joins 0.00154069709988 seconds.
The thread 1 runs  0.00006628699975 seconds.
The thread 1 forks 0.00575844590039 seconds.
The thread 1 joins 0.00199278510008 seconds.
The thread 2 runs  0.00006636039980 seconds.
The thread 2 forks 0.00551087460044 seconds.
The thread 2 joins 0.00224028299999 seconds.
The thread 3 runs  0.00006544990010 seconds.
The thread 3 forks 0.00564311910020 seconds.
The thread 3 joins 0.00210894899992 seconds.
With n = 12000 trapezoids, our estimate
of the integral from 1.000000 to 2.000000 = 2.33333333449074e+01
```

I don't know why the cost of forking 4 threads is so expensive compared with forking 2 threads.
Is there some issues on my method of measuring time?

Comment: 1/ you should use `-O3` in addition, because at the moment, you disabled any optimisations. And 2/ how many cores do you have? 2 right? Each with 2 hardware threads? Well, if so, you've just discovered that a hardware thread isn't a core...

Comment: @Gilles Hi Gilles, my CPU is i3. I googled just now, it says that i3 is dual-cores CPU, so I think it may be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your measuring time is fine. Without any optimization, the increasing number of threads will entail more administration/synchronization. However, with `-O3` optimization, you'll see clear speedups. I have 8 threads, so my runtime for 2,4,6,8 respectively are:

```
The global run time is 0.00013457789901 seconds.
The global run time is 0.00006983749627 seconds.
The global run time is 0.00004531119484 seconds.
The global run time is 0.00032387300453 seconds.
```

Notice how the runtime increases again when it hits 8 threads. This is one of the common problems in parallel programming. Your potential speedups in computations need to be large enough to justify the increasing cost of communications with more processors. In this case, 8 threads are even slower than single-threaded program (`The global run time is 0.00025965359819 seconds.`)

**EDIT:**
The number of physical cores and number of threads are indeed different. One way to check is `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. The output will list your threads. My guess would be there are 4. This is called [hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) to increase parallelism. Your program, however, uses threads, not cores for computation in both cases.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Besides that, my CPU is i3. it is dual-cores CPU, so I think it may also be part reason.

Comment: My laptop is 4 threads, I think  hyper-threading may make speedup decrease instead of making it rise.